# Woocommerce analytics are not showing the latest revenue field since last 1 month

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, analytics

Woocomerce analytics are not showing the latest revenue for the last three days. I tried to re-import the Historical Data but it is stuck on Initializing or Import data stage and not proceeding forward.

Also i updated the woocommerce database but it is still "in Progress" mode since last three days.

All Actions at woocommerce schedule sections are pending.

What is the issue and what can be the solution?

[See the action pending Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VmjG.png)

[Historical data is still in progress and not proceeding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pW4NE.png)